# Is there a way to create an xml element in python with special characters in its string?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Im writing a little python tool to help me organize and analyse some data. Unfortunately some of the data contains certain characters that seem to not work in an xml Element (such as '/')

Is there a way to keep this information in the string and still create an xml element with that name?

replacing the character alters the data and makes it partially unsusable

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
from xml.dom import minidom


class Rule:
name: str
rule_type: str
usage: list
macros: list
features: list
local_functions: list
local_variables: list
return_value: str
info: str

def __init__(self, name, rule_type, usage, macros, features, local_functions, local_variables, return_value, info):
    self.name = name
    self.rule_type = rule_type
    self.usage = [elem for elem in usage]
    self.macros = [elem for elem in macros]
    self.features = [elem for elem in features]
    self.local_functions = local_functions
    self.local_variables = [elem for elem in local_variables]
    self.return_value = return_value
    self.info = info

def rule_to_xml(self):
    root = Element(self.name)
    root.append(Comment(self.info))
```

When feeding a name like '`foobar/2_barfoo`' I get an Exception:

> not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column XYZ

Comment: did you try using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: As I understand the xml usage within python by XmlEtree it is standard to use utf-8 when not otherwise specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The '/' character is [not allowed in XML element names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name). A possible solution might be to keep strings like `foobar/2_barfoo` in an attribute of the element, e.g.:

```
<myelement name="foobar/2_barfoo">...</myelement>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I implemented it by giving the class a new attribute filename and just replacing the unwanted characters in the name with '_' to make it work and writing the filename as an attribute to my root node in the xml. I would like to give +1 but I am too new to posting here :/

Comment: Sorry. Did that now :)